# Recover Server 2012 password I CAN RDP

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, password-recovery

I have a domain joined machine that I log in to with a LOCAL MACHINE password via remote desktop.

I saved the password in RDP, but want to log in from a different machine, but have not used the password for so long I have forgotten it.

Cain and Abel seems useless in Server 2012.

What's the best way to recover a password on a machine I can log into with machine admin?

**Trying not to reset the password because the admin account is used as a service account for a few dev projects**

Comment: It's going to be much quicker for you to just suck it up and change the account's password and then re-configure your services than to derp around trying to crack the password.

Comment: EEAA is right. Also, the situation can become worse if the account is accidentally locked. (Even your stored password will be useless in that case). Anyway, this tool might worth a try: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/remote_desktop_password.html

Answer (score 1):

Get someone with domain admin privileges to make your domain account an administrator on that box.  EEAA is right that it would be faster to change the password on that account than it would be to crack it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Easy Transfer Wizard.

Optional (save some space, time):
Uncheck Documents, Music, Pictures, Videos

The tool grabs internet explorer passwords, It would follow that it would grab RDP sessions as well.

Here is the download (if below windows 7):
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer

or 
http://windows.microsoft.com/is-is/windows/transfer-files-settings-from-another-computer#1TC=windows-7